# Sum columns based on 'type' column

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

I need to sum a column based off of a 'type' column. For example, I have four items and two columns,

```
Type 1  |  val
Type 1  |  val
Type 2  |  val
Type 2  |  val
```

I need the sum of all Type 1 items, Type 2 items, etc. in an out-of-the-box solution or SharePoint Designer. I'm going to use an Excel Web Query to grab the information, so this needs to display **just** the type and the summed values.

EDIT:

For a bit better information in understanding exactly what it is I need, the situation would look like this;

```
List:
Type 1  |  2
Type 1  |  3
Type 2  |  4
Type 2  |  5

Result:
Type 1  |  5
Type 2  |  9
```

I've tried using SharePoint designer DVWP with a footer for each type, then summing the nodeset and then deleting the rows above and leaving just the footers. Problem is, it doesn't show all information.

Comment: Everyone who wants to do BI stuff is using 2007 these days, if you need to do any reporting, collation of data etc in SharePoint I strongly recommend moving to SharePoint 2010 and taking advantage of the wealth of BI tools available instead of patching things together. PowerView and PowerPivot are amazing tools and they can make connections to almost any data source including ssas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If layout/display is not an issue then probably you can create ListView with Group By and Total options. This will give you exact result what you need to show.
I had created one list view where I am showing total price per product category.
Here is my list view screen shot if this is something similar to what you want to show

[image: List view screen shot]

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Care to explain how to enable the totaling? The question asks HOW to do this.

Comment: This actually set me on the path to find the answer, THANKS! It got me thinking more on totals... I just used a DVWP in SPD, grouped it by the type, added a sum footer, and used the sum($nodeset/@column) for each column, then deleted the rows and left the footer. Using SPD, I could format it perfectly for the Excel Web Query! Thanks again.